# Execute a statement while debugging in Rust

Tags: debugging, rust

While Coding in Python, I often do something like

`test.py`

```py
x = []
breakpoint()
```

```sh
± |master U:5 ?:4 ✗| → python3 test.py 
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) x
[]
(Pdb) x.append(1)
(Pdb) x
[1]
```

Is it possible to execute the statement while debugging Rust?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() { 
    let mut contacts = HashMap::new();

    contacts.insert("Daniel", "798-1364");
    contacts.insert("Ashley", "645-7689");
    //set breakpoint here
}
```

So far, I can execute `p contacts` in the debug console, the meaning of this output isn't straight to me. What if I want to know the outcome of `println!("{:?}", contacts);` without writting this line of code in the source file.

And also I want to know the outcome of `contacts.insert("Robert", "956-1742")`, If I execute `expr contacts.insert("Robert", "956-1742")` in the debug console, it says `error: no field named insert`.

Comment: What debugger are you using? Please provide the version.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin `lldb-1100.0.30.12`

Comment: Check out the [`expr` command](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#evaluating-expressions), though I'm not sure it'll work with a Rust macro.

Answer (score 9):

Rust debugging support is currently quite limited with both lldb and gdb. Simple expressions work, anything more complex is likely to cause problems.

My experience while testing this with `rust-lldb`:

- The expression parser only understands a limited subset of Rust. Macros are not supported.
- Functions that are not used are not included in the resulting binary. E.g. you cannot call `capacity()` on the `HashMap` in the debugger since that function is not included in the binary.
- Methods have to be called like this: `struct_value.method(&struct_value)`
- I haven't found a way to call monomorphized methods on generic structs (like `HashMap`).
- String constants "..." in lldb expressions are created as C-style string constants, e.g. `"abcdef"` is a `const char [7]` including the trailing NUL byte. Thus they cannot be easily passed to Rust functions expecting `&str` arguments.

Trying to use a helper function like this:

```rust
pub fn print_contacts(contacts: &HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    println!("{:?}", contacts);
}
```

causes lldb to crash:

```
(lldb) expr print_contacts(&contacts)
PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: [...]
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So it seems that what you want to do is not possible at this time.

Comment: For monomorphized functions, each generated version of a function will have a different name (and maybe name mangling too?) So, you might have to look up the function name via the ASM or LLVM bitcode in order to call the functions.

Comment: @egerhard I thought so too, but I can't figure out how to call them. The expression parser does not support names like 
debugtest\`std::collections::hash::map::HashMap$LT$K$C$V$C$S$GT$::len::hb9c2954f4d0de90b` or debugtest\`hashbrown::map::HashMap$LT$K$C$V$C$S$C$A$GT$::len::h48d113d02acf7feb nor std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<&str, &str, std::collections::hash::map::RandomState>::len()

Comment: Yeah, that was a long shot, the expression parser probably has to have valid Rust expressions and can't just call assembly code labels. Getting this to work would probably require changes to the expression parser or something else in lldb.